# Add Page Number Navigation to Angular Material Paginator

Tags: angular-material

Is there a way to add page number navigation to mat-paginator along with the mat-paginator pageSizeOptions dropdown and functionality?  I have a design requirement as described below:

- Show page numbers in between navigation Next/Previous page navigation and only show 3 page numbers at a time
- Show items per page dropdown
- page numbers and arrow navigation need to be centered on page while show items is right justified

I have tried many solutions and the closest I got was using the solution in this [article](https://dev.to/krivanek06/angular-matpaginator-custom-styling-dkb)

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ufwhaw?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fsimple-table%2Fsimple-table.component.html,src%2Fbubble-pagination.directive.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

However I can't seem get the pageSizeOptions to work in conjunction with the custom pagination

Comment: If you are using [MatPaginator](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api) you'll see there is no native support for what you are trying to do. The medium article you posted is probably your best way to accomplish this without making a custom component to do all the heavy lifting. Material is pretty strict on expected behaviors - especially as of late - but overall making the components specialized to one behavior makes them more reliable.